# Smalltalk - is there something similar to && from C?

Tags: smalltalk, operator-precedence

I have to write a pure-object Smalltalk program, in which I need to evaluate conditions until one of them fails. I know that in C, we can use the `&&` operator for this, and conditions only get evalutated if necessary.

Is there something similar in Smalltalk?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you asking about the second part of a conditional not being evaluated unless it needs to be? If so, there's the `&` operator where the second half is always evaluated whether or not the first half is `false`, and there's `and:` where the argument (a block) is only evaluated if the receiver is `true`.

Comment: So if I have A and: [ B ] B would only be evaluated if A was true? that was exactly my question, I'll try to be more clear in my next questions. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer below to clarify. I'd still recommend re-wording your question even though you already have your answer - to make it easier for the next person wondering about the same thing.

Comment: @Amos M. Carpenter I just changed the title, hope that clarifies most of it, if it's still unclear I will edit later, I'm kind of in a rush.

Comment: Since you still seem to be too busy to edit your question, I've taken the liberty of trimming it down to what I think is its essence. The bit about "infinite" fields, about polymorphism and about your particular monster excercise (more appropriate for a comment, perhaps) were not really relevant to the question, and having everything in one huge paragraph made it rather unreadable (which is not just important in coding). Please have a look, and feel free to edit further if you feel something vital needs to be added back in.

Comment: Thanks, @AmosM.Carpenter I didn't know exactly what you meant about it, but I understand what you did, and will definitly keep that in mind for my next questions, your edit might make more useful the question I made, for someone with a similar doubt in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conditional "*and*ing" can be achieved by using the `&` message, or the `and:` message.

```
firstBooleanExpression & secondBooleanExpression
    ifTrue: [ 'do something' ].
```

Using `&` as show above, the second part of the condition (`secondBooleanExpression`) is evaluated regardless of whether the first half evaluates to `true` or `false`.

```
(firstBooleanExpression and: [secondBooleanExpression])
    ifTrue: [ 'do something' ].
```

Using `and:`, on the other hand, the second part is only evaluated if the first half evaluates to `true`. Typically you'd use this form, unless you explicitly *wanted* to evaluate the second half.

The same principle applies to `or:`.

Comment: Just for the record, everything in Smalltalk, at least in Pharo is left to right associative, also in (firstBooleanExpression or: [secondBooleanExpression]) secondBooleanExpression won't be evaluated if firstBooleanExpression is true, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But keep in mind that messages have a precedence order: unary messages (no arguments) have higher precedence.

Comment: Yes, @MaxLeske I know... the order is: unary operators, binary operators, and keywords, what I don't know what exactly keywords, mean.

Comment: @MaxLeske: Most Smalltalk dialects also have the three singleton pseudo variables `nil`, `true`, and `false`, and I believe not all dialects have `thisContext` (but I could be wrong there).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you're looking for something like this:

`[ <condition> ] whileTrue: [ <loop body> ]`.

`#whileTrue:` is not a keyword of course and you could implement it yourself (look at the implementation in your Smalltalk of choice and be enlightened :)).

If you don't need a loop but are simply looking for a way to express conditionals then `#ifTrue:`, `#ifFalse:`, `#ifTrue:ifFalse:` and `#ifFalse:ifTrue:` are your friends. Examples:

```
myCollection isEmpty ifTrue: [ Transcript open; show: 'empty'; cr ].
myCollection isEmpty ifFalse: [ Transcript open; show: 'not empty' cr ].
myBoolean
    ifTrue: [ Transcript open; show: 'true'; cr ]
    ifFalse: [ Transcript open; show: 'false'; cr ].
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, except that in this particular case shouldn't it be `[ aMonster isNotPathetic ] ifTrue: [ aZone attack: aMonster ]` ?

Comment: I've added the use of conditionals to my answer. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Pretty much, actually @Amos M. Carpenter  's answer was more precise, but yours is helpful too, even though I kind of realised myself that ifTrue: or ifFalse: could do the trick I was wondering if it existed something in smalltalk, something similar to && from C.

Comment: @newbie I think the message here is that, yes, although there may be a mechanism in Smalltalk that is similar to that in C, there may be a better pattern to follow in Smalltalk depending upon the scenario. Direct mappings from one language to another don't often lead to the best implementation.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind @lurker thanks for the advice.